# jquery dialog close event never fires?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following setup for my jquery ui dialog.

```
$("#dayEditForm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 475,
        width: 750,
        title: "Edit",
        modal: true,
        show: 'drop',
        hide: { effect: "drop", direction: "right" },
        open: function () {
            $("#editForm").validate();
        },
        close: function () {
            alert("closing dialog");
            $("#editForm").resetForm();
        },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                var isValid = $("#editForm").valid();
                if (isValid) {
                    // Save stuff here
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

However, the `alert("closing dialog")` in the "close" event never shows.  What have I done wrong?

UPDATE:
If I remove this line

```
hide: { effect: "drop", direction: "right" }
```

from the dialog definition, then it works fine...

Is this a bug?  Or expected behavior?

Comment: I, too, experience problems using the `close` event now and again. Although I can't explain why, try changing that event to `beforeClose` and see if that does the trick, it usually does so for me.

Comment: I  just moved the "resetForm" into the open part.  I just want the form to be reset before the user sees it next time, so that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug that was resolved in a later version. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13458978/469643). jQuery-ui 1.9.1 is a good bet for having this resolved.

If you don't want to upgrade your source, Goran's point in the comment works as well for me. Swap out the `close` event for `beforeClose` and it should fire and be roughly equivalent depending on what you hope to accomplish.

Thanks for posting the question and figuring out the correlation with `hide` option!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `"Cancel"` instead of just `Cancel` in the `buttons` part.